# Transformar linha em coluna Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Devido à necessidade de realizar um relatório personalizado, existe a necessidade de transformar colunas em linhas

Por exemplo:

Tenho a seguinte query

```
SELECT  
        case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 'gain'
              when resultado_operacao < 0 then 'loss'
              else 'zerada'
         end titulo 
         ,case 
           when resultado_operacao > 0 then 
              COUNT(case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           when resultado_operacao < 0 then   
                COUNT(case when resultado_operacao < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           else COUNT(case when resultado_operacao = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
          end contagem 
        ,COUNT(*) total
        ,extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) hora
  FROM gerenciamento_dados.tb_importar_operacoes io
  WHERE extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) IN (9, 10)
  group by extract(hour from io.abertura_hora), resultado_operacao
```

Que traz resultados parecidos com esse:

```
| titulo |  contagem  | total | hora |
|  loss  |     1      |  1    |   9  |
|  loss  |     1      |  1    |   9  |
|  loss  |     1      |  1    |  10  |
|  loss  |     1      |  1    |  10  |
|  gain  |     1      |  1    |   9  |
|  gain  |     1      |  1    |   9  |
|  gain  |     1      |  1    |  10  |
|  gain  |     1      |  1    |  10  |
```

Eu transformei essa query em um `WITH`

```
WITH valores as (SELECT  
        case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 'gain'
              when resultado_operacao < 0 then 'loss'
              else 'zerada'
         end titulo 
         ,case 
           when resultado_operacao > 0 then 
              COUNT(case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           when resultado_operacao < 0 then   
                COUNT(case when resultado_operacao < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           else COUNT(case when resultado_operacao = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
          end contagem 
        ,COUNT(*) total
        ,extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) hora
  FROM gerenciamento_dados.tb_importar_operacoes io
  WHERE extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) IN (9, 10)
  group by extract(hour from io.abertura_hora), resultado_operacao
 )
```

Continuando eu transformei esse conteudo em modelo mais resumido

Exemplo:

```
 select titulo
           ,'h' || lpad(hora::text,2,'0') hora  
           ,sum(total)        
     from valores
     group by titulo, hora
     order by hora
)
```

Que traz o seguinte resultado

```
| titulo  | sum | hora
| gain    | 849 | h09
| loss    | 699 | h09
| zerada  | 133 | h09
| gain    | 621 | h10
| loss    | 432 | h10
| zerada  | 92  | h10
```

E converto para `WITH`

```
WITH dados AS (
select titulo
               ,'h' || lpad(hora::text,2,'0') hora  
               ,sum(total)        
         from valores
         group by titulo, hora
         order by hora    
)
```

E por fim, trago somente os horários listados

```
select distinct hora from dados  order by 1
```

Essa query traz o resultado:

```
 |  hora  |
 |  h09   |
 |  h10   |
```

E converto para WITH

```
WITH horario AS (
select distinct hora from dados  order by 1 )
```

Tendo todos esse valores e queys testadas, faço a junção para usar no `crosstab`

```
  with valores as (
  SELECT  
        case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 'gain'
              when resultado_operacao < 0 then 'loss'
              else 'zerada'
         end titulo 
         ,case 
           when resultado_operacao > 0 then 
              COUNT(case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           when resultado_operacao < 0 then   
                COUNT(case when resultado_operacao < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           else COUNT(case when resultado_operacao = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
          end contagem 
        ,COUNT(*) total
        ,extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) hora
  FROM gerenciamento_dados.tb_importar_operacoes io
  WHERE extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) IN (9, 10)
  group by extract(hour from io.abertura_hora), resultado_operacao
 ),
 dados as (
    select titulo
           ,'h' || lpad(hora::text,2,'0') hora  
           ,sum(total)       
     from valores
     group by titulo, hora
     order by hora
),
horario as (select distinct hora from dados  order by 1 )       
  

SELECT *
  FROM crosstab(
    $$ select * from dados $$,
    $$ select * from horario $$
 ) AS t (
    titulo text, h09 text, h10 text
 )
```

Mas a seguinte query com o crosstab produz o seguinte resultado

**SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "horario" does not exist**

O resultado que eu gostaria de produzir é este:

```
| titulo  | h09  | h10  |
|   gain  |  10  |  15  |
|   loss  |  7   |  6   |
| zerada  |  2   |  4   |
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Ao tentar usar tudo dentro dos selects

```
select *
  from public.crosstab(
    $$ 
     select  titulo
        ,'h' || lpad(hora::text,2,'0')  hora
       ,sum(contagem)
       
   from (
  SELECT  
        case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 'gain'
              when resultado_operacao < 0 then 'loss'
              else 'zerada'
         end titulo 
         ,case 
           when resultado_operacao > 0 then 
              COUNT(case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           when resultado_operacao < 0 then   
                COUNT(case when resultado_operacao < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
           else COUNT(case when resultado_operacao = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
          end contagem 
        ,COUNT(*) total
        ,extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) hora
  FROM gerenciamento_dados.tb_importar_operacoes io
  WHERE extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) IN (9, 10)
  group by extract(hour from io.abertura_hora), resultado_operacao
 ) a
 group by titulo, hora
 order by 2
    $$,
    $$ 
        select distinct hora from (
            select  titulo
                   ,'h' || lpad(hora::text,2,'0')  hora
                   ,sum(contagem)
                   
               from (
              SELECT  
                    case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 'gain'
                          when resultado_operacao < 0 then 'loss'
                          else 'zerada'
                     end titulo 
                     ,case 
                       when resultado_operacao > 0 then 
                          COUNT(case when resultado_operacao > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
                       when resultado_operacao < 0 then   
                            COUNT(case when resultado_operacao < 0 then 1 else 0 end)
                       else COUNT(case when resultado_operacao = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
                      end contagem 
                    ,COUNT(*) total
                    ,extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) hora
              FROM gerenciamento_dados.tb_importar_operacoes io
              WHERE extract(hour from io.abertura_hora) IN (9, 10)
              group by extract(hour from io.abertura_hora), resultado_operacao
             ) a
         group by titulo, hora
         order by 2
       ) b 
       $$
 ) as t (
    id text, h09 int, h10 int
 )
```

Tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
| id     |  h09  | h10     |
| gain   |  849  |  [NULL] |
| loss   |  699  |  [NULL] |
| zerada |  133  |  [NULL] |
| gain   |[NULL] |   621   |
| loss   |[NULL] |   432   |
| zerada | [NULL]|   92    |
```

Onde a primeira consulta traz o seguinte resultado:

```
|  titulo  |   hora  |  sum  |
|  gain    |   h09   |  849  |
|  loss    |   h09   |  699  |
|  zerada  |   h09   |  133  |
|  gain    |   h10   |  621  |
|  loss    |   h10   |  432  |
|  loss    |   h10   |  92   |
```

E a consulta dois traz o seguinte resultado

```
|  hora  |
|   h09  |
|   h10  |
```